# SendRedirect not working from JSP Scriptlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, url, redirect

I have a main.jsp.

`Onclick` on a button in main.jsp, I am launching my JSP scriptlet in another window. In the JSP Scriptlet, I am processing URL parameters and constructing the URL. 
URL construction works fine; I print it in the log file and manually open the link constructed.

I want to redirect this JSP scriptlet page to the new URL constructed (different domain), in order to send redirect.

I am putting this line at the end after constructing the URL.

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

When I try to `sendRedirect` nothing happens. Can anyone please help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Please paste your JSP. Probably you can not send the redirect back to the browser because the response has already been committed.

Comment: If the response is already committed then i would have got that error atleast. In the backend when I am printing the msg in the log, it says redirecting to the new url. But in actual, it doesn't redirect. The page displays blank.

Comment: @smiley: Try writing response.flush(); and return; after sendRedirect line. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location= .. didn't work for me.

I did this and it worked

```
 <script> 
window.location.href = "<%= url %>";
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To call the JavaScript in this scriplet use

```
url = urlBuffer.toString(); 
System.out.println("url from JS server="+url);    
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location=<%=url%>
</script>
```

Comment: In main.jsp Javascript I am doing window.open() to call my JS Scriptlet from main.jsp. From scriptlet.jsp I need to send redirect to the new url which I am constructing in the scriptlet. How do we redirect from this page. this page does not have any html controls. So, if i call javascript, where should i call from?

Comment: Please post the jsp which you use to construct the url

Comment: Added my JSP code, please check and let me know. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Onclick - is postback or callback event? Do you use ajax? When you using ajax request, you can add code to success event: `document.location='some url';` When postback - `document.location='<%= url%>';`

Comment: In my case it is postback -> loading a new url in the same page.  But my question is, I am not using any html in this code. So if i put this document.location='<%= url %>'; in the JavaScript, how will I call the JavaScript in this scriptlet?